# regex exact match in function

Tags: javascript, regex

my function below searches a table, currently it searches for anything like, i want it to do an exact match, could you help me out?

Thanks

```
function searchTable(inputVal, tablename) {
    var table = $(tablename);
    table.find('tr:not(.header)').each(function (index, row) {
        var allCells = $(row).find('td');
        if (allCells.length > 0) {
            var found = false;
            allCells.each(function (index, td) {
                var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                    found = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (found == true) $(row).show().removeClass('exclude'); else $(row).hide().addClass('exclude');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "currently it searches for anything like, i want it to do an exact match" : Maybe you can tell us what it supposed to find.

Comment: What is `inputVal`, also look at regex anchors: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your current Regex is case insensitive.  An exact match would imply case sensitivity.

```
var regExp = new RegExp("^" + inputVal + "$", 'i');  // case insensitive
```

or

```
var regExp = new RegExp("^" + inputVal + "$");  // case sensitive
```